# What to do if HttpServletResponse.getWriter() throws an IOException?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, ioexception

The function HttpServletResponse.getWriter() actually throws an IOException, when that happens, the ideal thing to do is send an 500 status in the response, is there a way to do that without a viable PrintWriter?

Comment: This is the default behavior already, provided that the IOExcepiton isn't actually caused by the client itself aborting the request/response and thus willfully not being interested in the response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,
You can do that via `HttpServletResponse` using `sendError()` function.

You can do something like this:

```
response.sendError(SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "your error message");
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that sendError throws an IOException too. Does it means there will alway be a posibility when the client won't get anything from server?

Comment: @MorrisTown yes, there will alway be a posibility, but the common case of it would be Request timeout (when your request exceed time limit and you get no response from server)

Comment: you can learn more about http request life cycle